# Find/Replace Pascal Case EXCEPT when prepended by particular field (e.g. data-control=")

Tags: regex

I have an existing RegEx to match PascalCase in certain scenarios:

```
([^\w<\->\s])([A-Z][a-z]+)((?:[A-Z][a-z]+)*)
```

I'm looking for a way to NOT match when these groups are prepended by `data-control=` or `name=` or `id=`.

Example Input:

```html
<input data-control="Phone2" ng-model="UserInformation.Phone2">
```

Desired Output:
I want to match on "UserInformation", "Phone2" in ng-model, but DON'T match on "Phone2" in data-control.

[Regex101 fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/sQJbA2/1)

Comment: I see no difference between input and output.

Comment: A negative lookbehind [seems to do the trick](https://regex101.com/r/zO4R00/1)

Comment: @0x263A was fiddling with this one and it seemed to bomb out on regex101 / Jetbrains, but thanks so much -- negative lookbehind is exactly what was needed. I was able to disqualify matches by compiling a list of what NOT to match, e.g. (?<!data-control=)(?<!id=)(?<!name=)([^\w<\->\s])([A-Z][a-z]+)((?:[A-Z][a-z]+)*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @0x263A for the suggestion in comments of using a negative **lookbehind** (I've only been looking into **lookaheads**, and been trying to engineer the wrong tool for this).

With their help, I was able to come up with a solution that disqualifies certain matches via a list type format (in this case, don't match if preceded by data-control=, id=, or name=):

```
(?<!data-control=)(?<!id=)(?<!name=)([^\w<\->\s])([A-Z][a-z]+)((?:[A-Z][a-z]+)*)
```

If I find a match of something I want to ignore additionally, I'll just add it to the list. Thanks all!